# UML sequence calls between entities without knowing about each other

Tags: oop, uml, class-design, sequence-diagram

Let's say we have a tiger who hunts for his prey, standing on a field. When the tiger starts hunting, he asks the field what is standing on that currently. After that, the tiger starts to eat them one by one. If it eats a hyena, then it bites him which in turn the tiger let the hyena go. If the tiger hunted more than two hyenas at once, it dies from their bites. If the tiger eats an antelop, the antelop dies.

I created a sequence, but as far as I know, it breaks the OOP principles. What should I change to fulfill the principles? How can the Hyena response for the eating method without the tiger let the hyena know about this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Indeed: It’s not up to the tiger to tell the hyena to bite it, nor the hyena to decide for the tiger to let it go. The tiger should not even know about the internals of the hyena ([principle of the least knowledge](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter)).

You need to decouple these two classes. A first step would be to hide the internals, abstracting the hunter and the prey into more general beings.

The next step could be to transfer the responsibility of the interaction between the involved beings in a field to a **[mediator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern)** that would take charge of the choreography of the exchanges, using only the known interface of the beings, which tiger and hyena specialize.